# python| how can I convert a 2d array to an array of pairs

Tags: arrays, list, python-3.x, numpy

So I have a 2D array (below)

```
array([[ 1,  1],
       [  1,   1 ]]
```

That I would like to convert into an array of paris (lon, lat)  just as below

[(1, 1),
 (1, 1)]

How can I do that ?

Comment: `list(map(tuple,arr))`.

Comment: You can also just treat the array you already have as an array of pairs: `pair1 = arr[0]`, `pair2 = arr[1]`.

Comment: thanks all .. your answers are helpful but I used the comment from @Divakar to fix my issue. can you add as an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: @Abdel-RahmanShoman I think it has been covered in at least one of the Q &A before. So, must be a duplicate. I would encourage you to post your own answer post using that code from the comment, if that worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has worked for me. Thanks @Divakar for the helpful comment

```
list(map(tuple,arr))
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by a list comprehension:

```
array = [[ 1,  1], [ 1,  1 ]]

list_of_tuples = [(x,y) for x,y in array]
```

A working example can be found [here](https://repl.it/IXzu/0).

Answer (score 1):

```
a = np.array([[ 1,  1],
       [  1,   1 ]])

a
Out[31]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1]])

#Iterate the array and convert each element to a tuple.
[tuple(e) for e in a]
Out[32]: [(1, 1), (1, 1)]
```

Comment: Code only answers are less likely to help others understand why something works. Please describe how this overcomes the original problem.